# Avoiding code duplication among gson deserializers

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a number of related objects which I am using gson to deserialize. Currently, each of the deserializers fully implements deserialization by themselves.

I want to figure out how to minimize the code duplication among them, possibly by dividing the work among multiple deserializers.

These are some examples I've already implemented and use:

```
public static class WeaponDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Weapon> {

    @Override
    public Weapon deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String name = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("name"), String.class);
        ItemQuality quality = json.getAsJsonObject().get("quality") != null ? context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("quality"), ItemQuality.class) : ItemQuality.Common;
        Availability availability = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("availability"), Availability.class);
        String description = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("description"), String.class);
        double weight = json.getAsJsonObject().get("weight") != null ? json.getAsJsonObject().get("weight").getAsDouble() : 0.0;
        WeaponClass weaponClass = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("class"), WeaponClass.class);
        WeaponType weaponType = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("type"), WeaponType.class);
        String damage = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("damage"), String.class);
        String penetration = json.getAsJsonObject().get("pen").getAsString();
        String range = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("range"), String.class);
        String rateOfFire = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("rof"), String.class);
        int clip = json.getAsJsonObject().get("clip") != null ? context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("clip"), Integer.class) : 0;
        String reload = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("reload"), String.class);
        Set<String> specialRules = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("special qualities"), new TypeToken<Set<String>>() {
        }.getType());
        Set<UpgradeOrCustomization> upgrades = json.getAsJsonObject().get("upgrades") != null ? context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("upgrades"), new TypeToken<Set<UpgradeOrCustomization>>() {
        }.getType()) : Collections.EMPTY_SET;

        return new Weapon(name, quality, availability, description, weight, weaponClass, weaponType, damage, penetration, range, rateOfFire, clip, reload, specialRules, upgrades);
    }
}
```

```
    public static class WeaponDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Weapon> {

    @Override
    public Weapon deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String name = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("name"), String.class);
        ItemQuality quality = json.getAsJsonObject().get("quality") != null ? context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("quality"), ItemQuality.class) : ItemQuality.Common;
        Availability availability = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("availability"), Availability.class);
        String description = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("description"), String.class);
        double weight = json.getAsJsonObject().get("weight") != null ? json.getAsJsonObject().get("weight").getAsDouble() : 0.0;
        WeaponClass weaponClass = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("class"), WeaponClass.class);
        WeaponType weaponType = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("type"), WeaponType.class);
        String damage = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("damage"), String.class);
        String penetration = json.getAsJsonObject().get("pen").getAsString();
        String range = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("range"), String.class);
        String rateOfFire = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("rof"), String.class);
        int clip = json.getAsJsonObject().get("clip") != null ? context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("clip"), Integer.class) : 0;
        String reload = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("reload"), String.class);
        Set<String> specialRules = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("special qualities"), new TypeToken<Set<String>>() {
        }.getType());
        Set<UpgradeOrCustomization> upgrades = new HashSet<>();
        for (JsonElement element : json.getAsJsonObject().get("upgrades") != null ? json.getAsJsonObject().get("upgrades").getAsJsonArray() : Collections.<JsonElement>emptySet()){
            upgrades.add(UpgradeOrCustomization.getByName(element.getAsString()));
        }

        return new Weapon(name, quality, availability, description, weight, weaponClass, weaponType, damage, penetration, range, rateOfFire, clip, reload, specialRules, upgrades);
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you show your approach in code so that we see your solution and can think of ways to improve it.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried and wish to optimize.

Comment: better use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for such questions

Comment: `new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Weapon.class);` -> finished. or if you want to be complicated [`new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString, Weapon.class);`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/deserializing-json-java-object)